# Sudoku Grid Generator

Tags: c, grid, sudoku

I have just started making my Sudoku game and I have made this function `grid` for creating a `6x6` Sudoku grid. I have used the `rand()` function for different numbers in each cell (currently it will only check rows for repetition of numbers). `rand()` is also used for random numbers of empty cells in each grid.

The problem is that sometimes the grid is perfect `6x6` and without any number repeating (in rows only), however, sometimes in some cells there are garbage values generated and sometimes the number of columns is increased. I don't understand what is causing the problem?

The Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
void grid(void) {
    int cell[6][6], row, col, s, i, j;
    char in = 'A';
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (row = 0; row <= 5; row++) {
        printf("\t\t\t[ |");
        for (col = 0; col <= 5; col++) {
            s = rand() % 6 + 1;
            if (s % 2 == 0)
            {
                cell[row][col] = rand() % 6 + 1;
                for (j = 0; j<col; j++) {
                    if (cell[row][j] == cell[row][col]) {
                        col--;
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            }
            else { printf("   | ", in++); continue; }
            printf(" %d | ", cell[row][col]);
        }
        printf("]\n\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    grid();
}
```

Comment: The Pico indentation style you're using may be fine for Pico, but C is not Pico.  Please use an orthodox C [indentation style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style) — I prefer Allman but many people prefer some variant of 1TBS.  Stick with one or the other of those and you'll not go far wrong.

Comment: In a 6x6 Sudoku board, you normally have 6 sub-cells of 2 rows and 3 columns, and you have to preserve the uniqueness of the 6 numbers in each sub-cell as well as in each line and each column.  Your code doesn't seem to be doing enough to match those criteria. In a 9x9 board, you'd have 9 subcells, each of size 3x3, with the numbers unique in each subcell as well as in each row and column. I wonder if you'd do better with randomly permuting an array of 6 items? (I've not coded a Sudoku generator; I don't know the best way to do it. But there are almost 700 questions on SO tagged [tag:sudoku]!)

Answer (score 0):

They are too many syntax errors in the code you post, and the format is quite horrible. Try editing it so we can help you !

> col--;
>   Maybe this is your problem, because if you `col--;` in your `for (col = 0; col < 6; col++)` loop, you will do more than 6 iterations.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I agree that the code in the question is not readable as written.  However, you would probably do better to wait until you have enough reputation (50 points) to comment than to add a comment as an 'answer'.  The `col--` isn't a major problem; it is a way to go back and have another try at generating a number when the number chosen is already in use.  The code may not be right in the algorithm, but the `col--` is not itself a problem automatically.

Comment: How can I get 50 reputation without responding ? (honest question not sarcasm) and sorry about the wrong answer :/

Comment: There are 3 main avenues to gaining reputation:  (1) asking good questions;  (2) giving good answers; (3) making edits to questions or answers that are deemed good.  You should find a question to which you know or can work out the answer — perhaps one which has been neglected for an hour or more, so you won't be in competition with the FGITW (fastest gun in the west) crowd — and provide a good answer to it.  Usually, that will net you some reputation.

Comment: Thank you for your advices :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but a commenter here did say to wait at least 1 hour...

To answer your question directly:

1. You get garbage values because you do not set values for `cell` when !`(s % 2 == 0)`.
2. You get more than 6 entries per row because your `c--` statement causes the `col` loop to execute more than 6 times (and you printf each time).

If you want to maintain the general structure of your logic, then do this in two passes - fill `cell` completely and then print the whole thing.  However, there are other problems.  You probably want to remove the `s % 2 == 0` check completely, and the first `continue` could be a `break` (or a `goto` if you really want to make people angry).